# AFNetworking for iOS Next Update for Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, alamofire, afnetworking

Currently i am doing IOS App Development and my projects works under AFNetworking Lib V3.2.1 also i am slowly migrating my app into the Swift with AutoLayout.

My clarification whether will get the AFNetworking Next version for Objective-C?. Because this lib last they was updated on May 2018 and its getting older now a days.

Better can I switch over my project into Swift with alamofire network lib.?

Suggestion require to proceed further.

Comment: Objective-C is old, there will be no updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Objective-C there will be no further updates. Apple now recommends to use swift in every project so why go for objective-c now as its old. Alamofire is very good wrapper written for networking. 
I would suggest you to start migrating your project to Swift by using Bridging-Header which serves purpose of using Swift & Objective-C in same project.